# joins from belongs_to where query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been trying joins from the has_many table and i'm able to get it like
Order has_many order_items

```
Order.joins(:order_items).where(order_items: {name: 'something'})
```

But if i try from belongs_to table like

```
OrderItem.joins(:order).where(order: {value: 'something'})
```

I tried searching with keyword belongs_to, joins i wasnt able to get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While in `joins` you put the association name, in `where` clause you should use the database table name (`orders` - plural)

```
OrderItem.joins(:order).where(orders: { value: 'something' })
```

Comment: It is working but again i have another problem ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "value", reason is it is enum field, so i should use only integer here?

Comment: @Anbazhaganp if it's enum, say `status`, you should do: `where(status: Model.statuses[:status_name])`

Comment: @Anbazhaganp don't forget to accept the answer since it solved your issue (checkmark near the answer's score)

Comment: Thanks @Andrey Deineko, you have helped me learn something new.

Comment: Wow - that's confusing!